# Bash join command outputs only one line

Tags: bash, join, aix

On an *AIX* system this command:

```
    join installed_versions.csv apps_status.csv
```

With the following input files:

1. *installed_versions.csv*

   ```
   app installed_version
   appA 3.5
   appB 3.5
   appC 3.5
   appD 4.3
   appE 5.4
   ```
2. *apps_status.csv*

   ```
   app status
   appA Running
   appB Running
   appC Running
   appD Running
   appF Check
   ```

Gives me only one line of output:

```
    app installed_version status
```

And I expect to obtain the following output:

```
app installed_version status
appA 3.5 Running
appB 3.5 Running
appC 3.5 Running
appD 4.3 Running
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Are you sure those are the exact contents of the files in question? Does dumping them with `xxd` or `hexdump` or similar show anything interesting? Can you get the lines from either file with the arguments to `join` for selecting which file to pull unmatched lines from?

Comment: I also can't reproduce the problem. If the files are looking as you posted them, the command should work

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your output only by having one of the two input files empty (with the header but without application information). Lets say that the content of apps_status.csv is "app status" Are you really sure that the files are containing the information you have provided?

Comment: Note that a key requirement for `join` is that the data is in sorted order on the columns to be joined.  It is not obvious from the data shown that you have this problem (the data shown doesn't), but it could be an issue.  There's really no way to help without data that accurately reproduces the problem.  I've tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.4.  I'm not sure who's tested on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly the desired output on my AIX machine,

Comment: Presumably you could add 'using the same command line as you used'.  But this isn't really an answer to what's up — and there isn't enough information in the question, and probably never will given that the question is a couple of years old.

Comment: Yea.  I hit "AIX" and "unanswered" to get a list of current AIX unanswered questions and started picking things off the top.  I guess that wasn't such a wise move.  I don't know how it is sorted by default but a lot of them were somewhat old.

Comment: It's fine to answer good questions selected like that.  It's more problematic if you answer dubious questions like this one.  Since you, and I, and several of the commentators on the question, can copy the data out of the question and get the expected answer, what is in the question is presumably not what the OP has on his machine.  But without more information from the OP about the data that he does have, we're all stuck — the question should be close 'not clear what you are asking' or 'off-topic — cannot reproduce' or 'off-topic — needs an MCVE'.  Anyway, no harm done yet.

Comment: I think it might be worth deleting this 'answer' — but it's up to you.  You're lucky that this is in a backwater where there aren't lots of people chomping at the bit to fire off down-votes.

Comment: Its curious that two people voted on the question.  The unasked question is "does AIX join have a problem with this input?" and that is more along the lines of what I was answering.  I'm fine with deleting the answer.  Or I could edit the answer to be longer.  I'm curious on your thoughts.  I don't know how to do the other things like close it or mark it as off topic.  I probably don't have enough points.